# jQuery animate from random position

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-animate

I have a series of panels that I'd like to animate from random positions with jQuery.

Basically, I want a series of panels with random 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left' properties. In effect, I want some panels to slide in from the top, some from the left etc.

I've made a start, but am struggling to figure out how I'd go about getting the current elements css position property, i.e. top, bottom, left or right. Bear in mind I want the property, not the value.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: But... Wouldn't every single element have a top, bottom, left, and right property? Because you don't set `position:top`, you do `position:absolute; top:30px`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) does not require you to know the current position of an element. You provide a map of CSS properties the element will move *toward*, and `.animate()` handles the rest.

Comment: I think that's the point: He (she?) isn't sure about how to randomly choose which property (top, bottom, left, right) to animate. Of course, I could be completely wrong.